# Objects are not valid as React child (its about firebase)

Tags: react-native

I've created a new react-native app. I only installed firebase via npm and imported it. I didnt do anything else but this is what i get when i run the app.

[This is the exact error that i get.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYZUF.png)

And this is the code. Its just default App.js that react-native already creates. I only imported firebase.

```js
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, {
  Component
} from 'react';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' +
    'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android: 'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return ( <
      View style = {
        styles.container
      } >
      <
      Text style = {
        styles.welcome
      } >
      Welcome to React Native!
      <
      /Text> <
      Text style = {
        styles.instructions
      } >
      To get started, edit App.js <
      /Text> <
      Text style = {
        styles.instructions
      } > {
        instructions
      } <
      /Text> < /
      View >
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF'
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to your question by editing it.

Comment: I added as you wished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `import firebase from 'firebase';` from App.js and change the class as below.

```
export default class App extends Component {
  initializeFirebase() {
    const firebase = require("firebase");
      firebase.initializeApp({
        apiKey: '<your_key>',
        authDomain: '<your_domain>',
        databaseURL: '<your_url>',
        projectId: '<your_projectID>',
        storageBucket: '<your_bucket>',
        messagingSenderId: '<your_id>'
      });
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.initializeFirebase();
  }

    ...

}
```

Comment: It worked as hell thank you so much! But I wonder why did this happen. Because it wasnt happening before. I'he always imported firebase like this since a year ago.

Comment: Yes, it did. But as far as I noticed, the current version (5.0.4) has this issue. Looks like 5.0.4 is buggy.

Answer (score 0):

Replace **import firebase from 'firebase';** with **const firebase = require('firebase');**

and do the code someting like this

```
componentWillMount() {
    firebase.initializeApp({
        apiKey: '------',
        authDomain: '------',
        databaseURL: '-----',
        projectId: '------',
        storageBucket: '----------',
        messagingSenderId: '-------'
    });
}
```